# How can we upload image from URL in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
image = driver.find_element_by_id('url-upload-input').send_keys('https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940')
time.sleep(20)
image_upload = driver.find_element_by_id("url-uploaded-preview-img")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", image_upload)
```

I am getting this error may i know how can we upload the image from URL

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/automation/check.py", line 38, in <module>
    image = driver.find_element_by_id('url-upload-input').send_keys('https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940')
  File "F:\automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "F:\automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "F:\automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "F:\automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Comment: According to the error message the problem is, that there is no element with ID 'url-upload-input' visible.

Comment: there is id  with  same name <input type="url" class="form-control" id="url-upload-input" placeholder="Provide an image URL">

Comment: Check `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id('url-upload-input')))`. Is it `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait for element to be visible:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "url-uploaded-preview-img"))
)
```